# Minimizing the Sum of Quadratic Form with Equality Constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

In a problem I need to minimize sum of $K$ quadratic costs as follows:

$$ \min_{\mathrm x_1,...,\mathrm x_K} \sum_{i=1}^{K}( \mathrm x_i^TA_i\mathrm x_i+\lambda\mathrm c_i^T\mathrm x_i), \; \text{s.t.} \sum_{i=1}^{K}\mathrm x_i=e $$

where $\mathrm x_i \in \Bbb{R}^n,i=1,...,K$, each $A_i$ is a symmetric real matrix, and $e$ is an all-ones vector.

Using the Lagrange function and Lagrange multipliers, the solution of above optimization problem can be obtained by solving a linear system of equations. However, for large $n$ and large $K$ this leads to very large linear system. So my question is can I solve this problem more efficiently.

In fact, can I do this minimization by minimizing each of the quadratic cost separately (with no constraint) and then normalizing the solutions to make them sum up to one (according to the constraint)?

Comment: What are the $A_i$'s?

Comment: If you were to solve each quadratic minimization separately, what constraint would you put on each subproblem?

Comment: I solve each quadratic sub-problem with no constraint and then normalize the solution of all sub-problems according to the constraint of main problem. However, I do not know whether I am doing the right thing or not.

Comment: Are your $A_{i}$ matrices positive semidefinite?  indefinite?  negative semidefinite?

Comment: The matrices $A_i$'s are symmetric positive semidefinite.

Comment: Solved it for you with only Matrix Multiplication (Size of $ n $). Enjoy...

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Accelerated Gradient Descent Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent#Fast_gradient_methods).
This means you'll stay only with Matrix Multiplication (And exploiting $ {A}_{i} $ being Symmetric can help with that).

But you actually need to use "Projected Sub Gradient", namely to calculate the projection of the solution onto the Domain.

### The Projection onto The Constrain

Let's define a vector $ z = \left[ {{x}_{1}}^{T}, {{x}_{2}}^{T}, \ldots, {{x}_{K}}^{T} \right]^{T} $.
The constrains is equivalent of:

$$ S * z = \boldsymbol{1}_{n}, \; S = \underset{\times K}{\left [ \underbrace{{I}_{n}, {I}_{n}, \ldots, {I}_{n}} \right ]} $$

Basically the matrix $ S $ sum over the $ i $ -th element of all $ x $ vectors.

Now, given a vector $ y \in \mathbb{R}^{nk} $, its projection onto the set $ \mathcal{S} = \left\{ x \mid S * x = \boldsymbol{1}_{n} \right\} $ is given by:

$$ \arg \min_{x \in \mathcal{S}} \frac{1}{2} \left\| x - y \right\|_{2}^{2} = y - {S}^{T} \left( S {S}^{T} \right)^{-1} \left( S y - \boldsymbol{1}_{n} \right) $$

Due to the special structure of $ S $ one could see it is equivalent to:

$$ {x}_{i} - \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{K} {x}_{i} - \boldsymbol{1}_{n}}{K}, \: i = 1, 2, \ldots, k $$

Namely spread the deviation equally on all elements.

Here is the code:

```
%% Solution by Projected Gradient Descent

mX = zeros([numRows, numCols]);

for ii = 1:numIterations
    for jj = 1:numCols
        mX(:, jj) = mX(:, jj) - (stepSize * ((2 * tA(:, :, jj) * mX(:, jj)) + (paramLambda * mC(:, jj))));
    end
    mX = hProjEquality(mX);
end

objVal = 0;
for ii = 1:numCols
    objVal = objVal + (mX(:, ii).' * tA(:, :, ii) * mX(:, ii)) + (paramLambda * mC(:, ii).' * mX(:, ii));
end

disp([' ']);
disp(['Projected Gradient Solution Summary']);
disp(['The Optimal Value Is Given By - ', num2str(objVal)]);
disp(['The Optimal Argument Is Given By - [ ', num2str(mX(:).'), ' ]']);
disp([' ']);
```

The full code is in my [Mathematics Q2199546 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2199546) (Specifically in [Q2199546.m](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/blob/master/Mathematics/Q2199546/Q2199546.m)).
The code is validated using CVX.